# Cleanup after PHP Session

Tags: php, session

I am new at PHP and even newer with PHP Sessions, but have been reading a lot about it; however, I haven't been able to find the answer to my problem. Here is a simplified version:
1 - user types in a name in a form on a page
2 - a php file gets the name, starts a session and creates a directory on the server for the user with some customized files that the user can view.

Here is the question:
Since this is not a true login mechanism there won't be a logout or session timeout and I don't want to impose a timeout. So as long as s/he has the browser page open the directory that was created for the user on the server should be still accessible. How do I know when the browser is closed and user is not using the session anymore so I can delete the custom directory on the server? Is there anything related to the session file that is on the server that can be used: for example, if the garbage collection cleans the session and it doesn't exist anymore then I could run a script to detect that and delete the directory associated with the deleted session.

What is not clear to me is what happens to sessions on the server if session_destroy() is never called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Since this is not a true login mechanism there won't be a logout or session timeout and I don't want to impose a timeout.

Actually - it is a true login mechanism - you have a user perform a login by "entering name on form" - then they are logged in. It is just different to a username.

You just dont have a "logout" mechanism.

You can not rely on a browser to tell you when it is closed, leaving etc - it is unreliable and will not work. Therefore - your best (and only real) solution is to check server side for the state of the session. Just create a CRON job that runs a php file every 15mins or so. Each time the php file is run - it checks all sessions for their last activity time. If the last activity time is longer than the timeout limit, then run your cleanup.

I know you said you dont want to "impose a timeout" - but you'll going to have to draw a line in the sand somewhere, and say "hey, if my users are inactive for X mins (or even X hours) - then it is safe to assume they have left and are not coming back!". Just set a really high threshold.

Comment: Was halfway through typing just this kind of thing! You just need a 'logout' button hooked to the session_destroy() function that users can click.

Comment: That would require a script to look into the directory where PHP stores the sessions as files. In case the last activity time is stored as a key in the session, it  needs to parse that out to decide. Else, it needs to rely on last-accessed-timestamp of the file, which may not be reliable. You dont know if PHP is caching the changes. Its best if you dont get in PHP's way of dealing with things.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I know when the browser is closed and user is not using the session anymore so I can delete the custom directory on the server?

Theoretically, you can never know that. You have two options. Each of the below options have its own advantages and disadvantages.

- Use body `onunload` event to send a request to the server to destroy a session. Wont work all of the times. Simplest example when user has two tabs open and closes one.
- Have an AJAX request hitting the server every 3 mins or so. Useless in long standing sessions. Ofcourse, you can customise the '3 mins' according to what you'd expect in a normal session.

> Is there anything related to the session file that is on the server that can be used

In the above case, you are manually destroying the session. You can delete the directories as well when you destroy the session.

> What is not clear to me is what happens to sessions on the server if session_destroy() is never called.

There is an expiration time of a session. You can 'get' it using:
`ini_get("session.gc_maxlifetime");`

and set it using:
ini_set("session.gc_maxlifetime","3600" );  //3600 in minutes.

Comment: So is it a fair assumption that the session file sits on the server till somebody deletes it unless its maxlifetime has reached in which case system gc will take care of it?

Comment: Yes, the session data stays till the lifetime set. Note that session data is different from the directories you create for the user.

Answer (score 1):

The very definition of "as long as the browser is open" is very tricky in a stateless HTTP connection. Long story short: You cannot *reliably* tell how long a browser window is open or when it is closed, simply due to the fact that there's no persistent connection between the browser and the server. The browser requests a page, the server delivers it, the connection is closed. The page may or may not still be open in the browser and the browser may or may not eventually come back to request another page. You just don't know.

That's why all server-side state, including sessions, is based on a timeout. If the client did not come back for x amount of time, you can *assume* he has left and discard the saved data.

Doing anything else is tricky and has drawbacks. For example, you could include a piece of Javascript on the page that fires off a request every once in a while, telling the server that the user is still there. This will put a higher burden on the server though, receiving constant heartbeats from many different clients when nothing is really happening.

Another way would be to hook into the `beforeunload` Javascript event, which you can use to detect when a user closes the page. That's absolutely not guaranteed to work all the time though, you won't receive every single pageunload on the server for various reasons. So even in this scenario, you'll need to discard old data eventually yourself.

The best way is to structure whatever it is you want to do around the idea of timeouts and removing of expired data, since this is the only really reliable way.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing. Absolutely nothing special happens. Seesions expire in some amount of time and require a re-authentication, which is just what happens when you session_destroy.

Comment: So all those session files sit on the server forever? _something_ must happen to them!

Comment: Session_destroy destroys those files, I think. I'm just saying nothing happens to the session, just a timeout, which happens anyway, so nothing changes..

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly default time-out for session is 1440 seconds, so it will expire automatically. If it is OK for you, then do nothing.